Detached vanity, now faucet supply line leaking
We are getting ready to retile our bathroom floor and removed our old vanity (functioned fine and no leaking) and now the faucet supply line won’t stop dripping.
We have hand turned the supply valve all the way closed but it still is dripping.
Is there a way to determine if the valve or supply line needs to be replaced?
Thanks for the help!
Our valve looks like this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-Sweat-Inlet-x-3-8-in-Compression-Outlet-Chrome-Plated-Multi-Turn-Angle-Valve-R19X-C1/202047062

easiest thing is piggy back valves.  they install on top of existing valves that don't quite work.  best thing is to do fully replace the valves but lazy plumbers do the piggy back thing all the time and aside from the weird double valve look it works just fine.

If water still comes out after the valve is close, then the valve is leaking.
Might be the washer is bad or stuff in the seat stopping sealing completely.
Fastest fix is to turn off main water valve and replace.  Some can be repaired/fixed, but takes a bit more time to find the problem and get repair parts/washer.

It is not uncommon for mineral deposits to get on the internal surfaces of the valves and/or the rubber washers to wear over time. Especially when the water has a higher chlorine content.
You have 2 options:
1- Turn off the water to the house and the electric to the Hot water tank.
(this , so the elements don't burn up if the water in the tank goes too low.)
Remove the handles of the shutoffs, and the nut around the stem. Rotate the stem counter clock-wise to remove it. You will find the washer at the base of the stem.  A screw holds it on. Replace the washer. Reinstall in reverse order. Be sure to close the valves. Turn your water back on.
2-  Turn off water and electric to the tank as in option 1.
Replace the valves. New valves are not a great expense. If you have enough piping behind the valves, cut the pipes square and install Push on valves
They are very reliable. Once The replacement valves are installed, be sure the valves are in the OFF position. Turn your water and electric to the tank back on. Done

Your valve probably simply needs to be repaired—the rubber seals deteriorate over time and exposure to water.  The valve in the faucet kept it from leaking before.
If it's the valve you link in your OP, BrassCraft makes a $3 repair kit: https://www.brasscraft.com/product/multi-turn-stop-stem-repair-kit/
Turn off the house water and drain the pipes by opening another valve or posibly the water heater (careful with hot water).  Unscrew and remove the knob.  Then use a pair of wrenches to loosen and remove the packing nut where the shaft comes out (you want to use one wrench to keep the valve body steady, so you don't ruin the seal it makes with the pipe).
